# How can I serve a file only if the user has purchased my product, on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

My data files include a demo version of my program as long as a complete, unlocked one. Google App Engine is used to serve webpages to the user. A database records whether the users have purchased a product, and based on that, I’d like to serve them file A-demo.exe or A-completeVersion.exe

I thought about calling `self.redirect( A-completeVersion.exe )` according to the purchase flag, but that would let the user see the URL of the complete version in his browser.

Is there something I could do to proceed with this download without the URI appearing in clear?

PS: by the way, I’m using the Python 2.7 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're requiring the users to log in, serve the "full" version from the [blobstore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Serving_a_Blob).  That would allow you to easily check that they've got a valid license before downloading the file.

If you're not requiring login, you could generate single use URLs that you serve the application from.  Once they have completed the purchase, generate a [uuid](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html) and write an entity to the datastore with that uuid as the key.  When they try to download, check and see if that key is valid.  If it is, update the entity to reflect that it was used and then [send the blob](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Serving_a_Blob).